# Angular - Why does Number.isNaN return false for a non-empty string?

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a dropdown that allow the user to select a value. When the selected item changes, it calls a function in my component (`onDropdownChange`). The value passed to `onDropdownChange` can be a string ("Please select an option") or the index number of a selected value.

Here's the onDropdownChange in my TypeScript file:

```
onDropdownChange(id: any) {
  if(Number.isNaN(id)){
    this.selectedIndex = null;
    this.isItemSelected = false;
  }
  else{
    this.selectedIndex  = id;
    this.isItemSelected = true;
  }
}
```

When the value of id is "Please select an option", `isNaN` returns `false`. Why?

When I use the '+' unary operator to return the number representation of the string in the code below, `isNan` correctly returns `true`. Why?

```
onDropdownChange(id: any) {
  // convert id to a number representation using '+'
  if(Number.isNaN(+id)){
    this.selectedIndex = null;
    this.isItemSelected = false;
  }
  else{
    this.selectedIndex  = id;
    this.isItemSelected = true;
  }
}
```

Here is the relevant code in my html template:

```
            <select class="form-control" (change)="onItemChange($event.target.value)">
              <option> Please select </option>
              <option *ngFor="let item of items; let i=index" [value]="i" [selected]="i === selectedIndex"> Item {{i+1}}</option>
            </select>
```

Comment: The best way to answer questions you have about things like this is to always consult the docs first. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isNaN

Comment: `When the value of id is "Please select an option", isNaN returns false. Why?` well it's a bit of a circular logic but...it's `false` because the string `"Please select an option"` is not the value `NaN`. It pretty much describes itself there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Number.isNaN()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isNaN)

> The Number.isNaN() method determines whether the passed value is NaN and its type is Number. It is a more robust version of the original, global isNaN().

If `id` is a string, then it is not a number, so `Number.isNaN()` returns false:

```js
console.log(Number.isNaN('Please select an option'));
console.log(Number.isNaN('foo'));
```

The only time to use `Number.isNaN()` is when you would want to, essentially, check to see if `someVariable === NaN`, which doesn't work by itself because `NaN !== NaN`.

For your case, just use the plain `isNaN`:

```js
console.log(isNaN('Please select an option'));
console.log(isNaN('foo'));
```

Answer (score 2):

`isNaN(id) === Number.isNaN(+id)`

There is only one value of `x` for which [Number.isNaN(x)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isNaN) evaluates to true: `NaN`:

```js
console.log( Number.isNaN( NaN ) );
console.log( Number.isNaN( 'foo' ) );
console.log( Number.isNaN( {} ) );
console.log( isNaN( '5' ) );
console.log( Number.isNaN( 0 ) );
```

That is in contrast to the global [isNaN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) function which returns `true` for anything that is `NaN` after coercing it to a number:

```js
console.log( isNaN( NaN ) );
console.log( isNaN( 'foo' ) );
console.log( isNaN( {} ) );
console.log( isNaN( '5' ) );
console.log( Number.isNaN( 0 ) );
```

Neither of those functions are meant to test if their argument is not a `number`. They are both meant for testing if their argument ***is*** the number `NaN`.